# How do I float 3 elements next to each other with specific order?

Tags: html, css

I have four elements, three of which I want to be side-by-side with the footer down below. The problem I have at the moment is that getting the order that I want without changing any of the HTML (the order, for instance).

I currently have this code:

```css
#nav {
  background-color: red;
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
}

#intro {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 15%;
  float: right;
}

#content {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 70%;
  float: right;
}

footer {
  background-color: magenta;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section id="intro">...</section>
  <div id="content">...</div>
  <aside id="nav">...</aside>
  <footer>...</footer>
</div>
```

Here you can see that what I get is the color order red, blue, and yellow. But the order I want is red, yellow, then blue.

Comment: You only want to swap the colors or swap complete div in order .intro .nav .content

Comment: No JS. And I don't need to float the elements if I don't have too. I just the order I specified to be shown. So on the browser I want nav -> intro -> content. Where the html is currently intro -> content -> nav

Comment: Don't use floats. It's an old, brittle, unnecessary approach. In many cases, flexbox will do what you want much more easily. For instance, in this case you might be able to use the `order` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` instead on the yellow div and remove the float

```css
#intro {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 15%;
  display:inline-block;
}
#nav {
  background-color: red;
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
}

#content {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 70%;
  float: right;
}

footer {
  background-color: magenta;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section id="intro">...</section>
  <div id="content">...</div>
  <aside id="nav">...</aside>
  <footer>...</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use flex. No need to use `float` and you can custom position of them later in other screen size if needed by change their `order`

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#nav {
  background-color: red;
  width: 15%;
  order: 1;
}

#intro {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 15%;
  order: 2;
}

#content {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 70%;
  order: 3;
}

footer {
  background-color: magenta;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  order: 4;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section id="intro">...</section>
  <div id="content">...</div>
  <aside id="nav">...</aside>
  <footer>...</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `flexbox` for this layout, instead of `float`. Then you can use the `order` property to position the items as you want.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#nav {
  background-color: red;
  min-width: 15%;
  order: 1;
}

#intro {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-width: 15%;
  order: 2;
}

#content {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1 0 70%;
  order: 3;
}

footer {
  background-color: magenta;
  flex: 1;
  order: 4;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section id="intro">...</section>
  <div id="content">...</div>
  <aside id="nav">...</aside>
  <footer>...</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Unclear, but do you want it to be responsive? Should the size-order still be the same? If not just change:

```
 <section id="intro">...</section>
  <div id="content">...</div>
  <aside id="nav">...</aside>
  <footer>...</footer>
```

To:

```
  <div id="content">...</div>
  <section id="intro">...</section>
  <aside id="nav">...</aside>
  <footer>...</footer>
```

Another solution could be to use Bootstrap.

Comment: Sry didn't notice that.

Answer (score -2):

if you want to only change the color of second div (.content) to yellow, you can simply change the color in css.

If you want to swap the div in that order check this snippet

```css
#nav {
  background-color: red;
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
}

#intro {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 15%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#content {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 70%;
  float: right;
}

footer {
  background-color: magenta;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section id="intro">...</section>
  <div id="content">...</div>
  <aside id="nav">...</aside>
  <footer>...</footer>
</div>
```

change style for `#intro`

```
#intro {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 15%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Alright, @Kodaloid what's the difference in my code and the code posted above (getting up votes). Please specify why you thought I missed the point.

Comment: The answer I responded too indicated you thought that changing the visual style was enough to accomplish the result, where as the question asked specifically about order of elements on the screen. I have noticed since I wrote my first comment on this answer that you have modified your answer and copied the highest voted answer (as can be seen in the edit history). Lets have a bit more maturity please.

Comment: lol. I never edited my answer. It was edited by some Sweller and even he did not changed the codes there he only edited the formatting. If you can please check again the timing of my answer and the above posted answer. I am not arguing because you commented but at least you should have checked the complete answer of mine. Also, I have mentioned both the scenarios in my answer because for me the question was not so clear. Anyways sorry. I should have not commented back on your comment.

Answer (score -3):

its better to use CSS Framework like Bootstrap that you can use easily of framework

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3"></div>
   <div class="col-md-6"></div>
   <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
```